# How can I return a substring based on CharIndex for starting and end points from a field in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on this problem most of the morning and I think I have the solution mostly but I must have something wrong somewhere.

I have a table that keeps as a column a long html file.

I need to search that column and return a part of that html file in mssql but I do not have index numbers to use.

My query so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColName, CHARINDEX('TxTStart', ColName), CHARINDEX('TxTEnd', ColName))
FROM htmlTable ht
WHERE ht.Date_ = '2009-01-01'
```

My thinking is that the length in this query will not be correct to obtain the whole substring from txtStart to TxtEnd.

Should I possibly use RTRIM, just take all the string and then cut off what I need after ?
Should the above actually work and I just have something else wrong?

Or am I completely off base here?

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

Comment: Can you shouw an example as to why you think that this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd parameter is length, so you need to subtract the end and start to get the length.  try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColName, CHARINDEX('TxTStart', ColName), CHARINDEX('TxTEnd', ColName) - CHARINDEX('TxTStart', ColName))
FROM htmlTable ht
WHERE ht.Date_ = '2009-01-01'
```

Comment: Your right I did not add a third parameter to subtract from which is why the length of the substring was also incorrect. I found this out by doing individual charindex searhces by themseleves to arrive at the correct length. Thanks so much for the quick responses.